# formControlName for mat-list gives 'mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components, mat-list

[StackBlitz (runnable example)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xijtrv-zxez15)

### Angular HTML template for Component

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="name" formControlName="name">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-list formControlName="foldersList">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let folder of folders"><h4 mat-line>{{folder.name}}</h4></mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

### Angular TypeScript Component

```typescript
export class MyComponent {
  folders = [ { name: 'Photos', updated: new Date('1/1/16') } ];

  myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    foldersList: 
           new FormControl([]),
           // new FormArray([]),
           // ['', Validators. Validators.required],
           // this.fb.array([], [Validators.required]),
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
}
```

---

### Errors

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'foldersList'
Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
```

Comment: Usually you don't put `mat-list` inside a `mat-form-field`. Maybe if you want the user to select something form the list, use `mat-select` or `mat-selection-list` instead.

Comment: Yeah in my actual code I have `mat-selection-list` with `mat-list-option` inside. Anyway, do you know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mat-list` and `mat-selection-list` components do not implement the `MatFormFieldControl` interface. Which is why they can not be used inside a `mat-form-field`.

Here's a working fork of the above example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xijtrv-yzpsmj

Just replaced `mat-list` with `mat-selection-list` and removed the `mat-form-field` that wrapped it.

Comment: Don't get it. You can not use `mat-list` and `mat-selection-list`. And now you solved it by using `mat-selection-list`. Can you explain it a bit more?